# Disassembling simple C function

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand the underlying assembly for a simple C function.

**program1.c**

```
void function() {
  char buffer[1];
}
```

=>

```
push  %ebp
mov   %esp, %ebp
sub   $0x10, %esp
leave
ret
```

Not sure how it's arriving at 0x10 here?  Isn't a character 1 byte, which is 8 bits, so it should be 0x08?

---

**program2.c**

```
void function() {
  char buffer[4];
}
```

=>

```
push  %ebp
mov   %esp, %ebp
sub   $0x18, %esp
mov   ...
mov   ...
[a bunch of random instructions]
```

Not sure how it's arriving at 0x18 here either?  Also, why are there so many additional instructions after the `SUB` instruction?  All I did was change the length of the array from 1 to 4.

Comment: Those numbers are bytes. They are bigger than what you asked for because of alignment and disabled optimizations.

Comment: Oh, so 0x10 is 10 bytes not 10 bits?

Comment: In this context count is done in bytes, counting in bits is pointless.

Comment: I would guess those numbers simply depend on the format of your stack frame.

Comment: @sir_thursday: `0x10` is hexadecimal, and it's not ten bytes, it's sixteen bytes. Also, if you'd enable optimizations, both functions would likely be turned into `ret;`.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant.. 16 not 10.

Comment: Add some more instructions, e.g. `printf("%c", buffer[0];`, otherwise the compiler may overoptimize.

Comment: @sir_thursday for fiddling around with this kind of stuff I'd recommend this very practical site : [https://gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org).

Comment: ^ Thanks for the resource!

Comment: This assembly doesn't make any sense, and it doesn't match the one I would expect to see there. Are you sure this is the full listing and it matches the C code?

Comment: @SergeyA: The mess of stuff in the 2nd function is from `-fstack-protector`, on by default in some gcc versions.

Comment: @SergeyA :See my comment under Peter's answer to Sir_thursday. Ubuntu has used a hardening wrapper around the real _GCC_ to add extra parameters. My guess is that Sir_thursday is using Ubuntu or a derivative. The output he has given would be consistent with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gcc [uses `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4` by default](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) for x86 32 and 64bit ABIs, so it keeps `%esp` 16B-aligned.

I was able to reproduce your output with [gcc 4.8.2 `-O0 -m32` on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g482,options:'-xc+-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-O0+-m32',source:'void+f1()+%7B%0A++char+buffer%5B1%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+f4()+%7B%0A++char+buffer%5B4%5D%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
void f1() { char buffer[1]; }
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp      # make a stack frame (`enter` is super slow, so gcc doesn't use it)
    subl    $16, %esp
    leave                   # `leave` is not terrible compared to mov/pop
    ret
```

You must be using a version of gcc [with `-fstack-protector`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) enabled by default.  Newer gcc isn't usually configured to do that, so you don't get the same sentinel value and check written to the stack.  (Try a newer gcc in that godbolt link)

```
void f4() { char buffer[4]; }

    pushl   %ebp  #
    movl    %esp, %ebp      # make a stack frame
    subl    $24, %esp       # IDK why it reserves 24, rather than 16 or 32B, but prob. has something to do with aligning the stack for the possible call to __stack_chk_fail
    movl    %gs:20, %eax    # load a value from thread-local storage
    movl    %eax, -12(%ebp) # store it on the stack
    xorl    %eax, %eax      # tmp59
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax # D.1377, tmp60
    xorl    %gs:20, %eax    # check that the sentinel value matches what we stored
    je      .L3 #,
    call    __stack_chk_fail        #
.L3:
    leave
    ret
```

Apparently gcc considers `char buffer[4]` a "vulnerable object", but not `char buffer[1]`.  Without `-fstack-protector`, there'd be little to no difference in the asm even at `-O0`.

Comment: Stack protector! Thanks for this.

Comment: This is an awesome answer.  Thank you

Comment: @sir_thursday : If you are using a Ubuntu derivative (I'm guessing you are) then GCC has a hardening wrapper around it that adds extra flags. For GCC<4.9 more recent Ubuntu releases will use `-fstack-protector --param ssp-buffer-size=4` and for GCC>=4.9 it uses `-fstack-protector-strong` . You could disable with `-fno-stack-protector`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I think it's not technically a wrapper.  `/usr/bin/gcc` is a symlink to `gcc-5`, which is an `867kiB` executable.  I think gcc lets you set defaults when building it, and that's how the Ubuntu packaging configures gcc.  But yeah, `stack-protector-strong` matches up with my observations of what happens in trivial functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Depending on your version of Ubuntu milage may vary. You may not have the GCC hardening package installed (it is generally installed by default now). The hardening wrapper if it exists is a perl script that sets up parameters and then calls the real compiler. (often called gcc-5.real etc). How it is implemented if it is would be a factor of the version of Ubuntu. Which version are you using? You may just have to install the package `hardening-wrapper` .

Comment: And as I recall the hardening package has been around since about 12.04, although I don't believe it was installed as a default package.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Ah ok, I wasn't aware of that package.  I'm on Ubuntu 15.10, from a fresh install of kubuntu-desktop 15.10 several months ago.  I don't have `hardening-wrapper` installed, but my gcc still defaults to `-fstack-protector-strong`, as I can see from the `-fverbose-asm` output, and the generated code.  `hardening-wrapper` is priority: extra, with no reverse-depends, so nothing ever pulls it in (other than if it was installed during a default install).  Maybe they baked the options into the gcc defaults and don't need to make the wrapper part of the default install anymore?

Comment: I have 15.10 in front of me (Ubuntu not Kubuntu) and in my case the wrapper was installed as a default.It may well be that it is automatically installed during initial package installation. My system is pretty much a default install on 15.10 and I haven't installed the hardening-wrapper directly. It is quite possible Ubuntu now compiles GCC with default hardening specs now. That wasn't always the case previously

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't a character 1 byte, which is 8 bits, so it should be 0x08?

This values are not bits, they are bytes.

> Not sure how it's arriving at 0x10 here?

This lines:

```
push  %ebp
mov   %esp, %ebp
sub   $0x10, %esp
```

Are allocating space on the stack, 16 bytes of memory are being reserved for the execution of this function.

All those bytes are needed to store information like:

- A 4 byte memory address for the instruction that will be jumped to in the `ret` instruction
- The local variables of the functions
- [Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)
- Other stuff i can't remember right now :)

In your example, 16 bytes were allocated. 4 of them are for the address of the next instruction that will be called, so we have 12 bytes left. 1 byte is for the char array of size 1, which is probably optimized by the compiler to a single char. The last 11 bytes are probably to store some of the stuff i can't remember and the padding's added by the compiler.

> Not sure how it's arriving at 0x18 here either?

Each of the additional bytes in your second example increased the stack size in 2 bytes, 1 byte for the char, and 1 likely for memory alignment purposes.

> Also, why are there so many additional instructions after the SUB instruction?

Please update the question with the instructions.

Comment: The return value as in the address which the function will return to, the address of the next instruction that will be called

Comment: But `call` pushes (and `ret` pops) the return address, meaning it was already on the stack before the function prologue shown

Comment: The return address is already on the stack (at `(%esp)`) on entry to the function.  That's why an empty function compiles to just a `ret` instruction, not a `sub $4, %esp / ret`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the ret memory address is included in the 16 byte allocation...

Answer (score 2):

This code is just setting up the stack frame. This is used as scratch space for local variables, and will have some kind of alignment requirement.

You haven't mentioned your platform, so I can't tell you exactly what the requirements are for your system, but obviously both values are at least 8-byte aligned (so the size of your local variables is rounded up so %esp is still a multiple of 8).

Search for *"c function prolog epilog"* or *"c function call stack"* to find more resources in this area.

**Edit** - *Peter Cordes' answer explains the discrepancy and the mysterious extra instructions*.

---

And for completeness, although Fábio already answered this part:

> Not sure how it's arriving at 0x10 here? Isn't a character 1 byte, which is 8 bits, so it should be 0x08?

On x86, `%esp` is the stack *pointer*, and pointers store addresses, and these are addresses of bytes. Sub-byte addressing is *rarely used* (cf. Peter's comment). If you want to examine individual bits inside a byte, you'd usually use bitwise (`&`,`|`,`~`,`^`) operations on the value, but not change the address.

(You could equally argue that sub-cache-line addressing is a convenient fiction, but we're rapidly getting off-topic).

Comment: The 386 bit-string instructions (`bt` / `bts` / `btr` / `btc`) actually do bit offsets to memory addresses.  e.g. `bt [bitmap], 1234` tests bit 2 in `[bitmap+154]`.  This is the kind of crazy-CISC semantics that unfortunately makes `bts [mem], reg` very slow: 10 uops on Intel Haswell.  (vs. 3 uops for `bts [mem], imm` or 1 uop for `bts reg, r/i`).  The CPU doesn't know the memory address until both operands are ready.

Comment: Eww, I wasn't aware of those, although I suppose I'm not entirely surprised. Serves me right for carelessly conflating C pointers, addresses, `%esp` and instruction operands.

Comment: C pointers and other stuff translate very directly to x86 machine instructions.  Compilers will use `bt*` instructions, but usually not with memory operands.  [I tried to get gcc / clang / icc to do an atomic test-and-set in a bitmap with `lock bts`](https://godbolt.org/g/sIGPfJ), but gcc just uses `lock cmpxchg` :(.  Even with `-Os`, it won't just use `bts` for the non-atomic version.

Comment: Even thinking about byte-aligned atomic instructions gives me the word-tearing horrors, so I'm probably happier not thinking about sub-byte ones.

Comment: `lock bts` actually produces an atomic read-modify-write on a whole byte at least.  From the insn ref manual entry for `bt`: "When accessing a bit in memory, the processor may access 4 bytes starting from the memory address for a 32-bit operand size".  BTS is listed as `BTS r/m32, r32`, so it apparently can fault if the bit offset + the given address takes you to a 4B chunk that crosses into an unmapped page.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you allocate memory, your operating system almost never actually gives you exactly that amount, unless you use a function like `pvalloc`, which gives you a page-aligned amount of bytes (usually 4K). Instead, your operating system assumes that you might need more in the future, so goes ahead and gives you a bit more.

To disable this behavior, use a lower-level system call that doesn't do buffering, like `sbrk()`. These lecture notes are an excellent resource:
http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/classes/cs360/360/notes/Malloc1/lecture.html

Comment: Although this is true, as written this is more relevant to malloc/new/mmap or other free store allocation, and there is exactly none of that happening here.